# Data Submit Interruption of html Form inserting data in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, router, wampserver

I have this problem where in my Applicant Quiz using php, javascript, mysql. Its a simple quiz created from html forms, with a .php for inserting in the database for the applicants answer. It has a timer of 10 minutes that auto-submits the form and sets the value of 0 to blank fields and get inserted into the database.

But the problem here is, sometimes, when submitting, it was not get inserted into the database, but sometimes it was succesfully submitted, I am using WAMP server, I have a desktop as the admin for monitoring submitted exams, and 6 laptops all connected through the same client network I created in the router, I am using ASUS BRT-AC828 Router.

should I connect all the devices on the original ASUS 2.4 network? rather than creating a client network named, GHS_Exams? could this be the one that affects why sometimes the submission didnt get inserted in the database?

Comment: What do you mean by a _Client Network_?

Comment: I currently using ASUS BRT-AC828 Router, and the default network is ASUS 2.4, but we are able to create a client network, or a separate one, with a different password, but still in the same router, the thing is, when the desktop along with the wamp server is connected on the client network (I named it "GHS_Exam"), the connection to the database does not getting longer enough and disconnects after several minutes, Like I can only submit a form for 10-15 minutes, and the next submission will fail to insert in mysql/phpmyadmin but when clicking submit, then form action still submitted.

Comment: But when connected to the original 2.4 network, there is no problem, like it can work for 24/7, is it not possible for the client setup network to handle the local server connection? I have 6 laptop connected on the GHS_Exam network,but, I want to know if I can separate their network to be more organized, like you can only access the exam link by connecting to that client network.

Comment: Is there a connection timeout need to disable or extend in the mysql, apache?