# html form successfully submitted to form action, but failed to insert in the database (Feb 20, 2020)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wamp

I have my Own Applicant Assessment Tool using PHP, Javascript and Mysql. The Form should be filled up with answers or it will be automatically submitted after 12 minutes, and leaves the blank fields value as zero. It is Fully functional and I will show you how to set it up!

this should be inserted to ghsexam.php

```
<script>
time = 720;
interval = setInterval(function() {
time--;
document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = "" + time + " seconds"
if (time == 0) {
    // stop timer
    clearInterval(interval);
    // click
    document.getElementById('thebutton').click();            
}
}, 1000)

</script>

<form id="locForm" name="locForm" target="" action="/ghs/ghsadd.php" method="post" >


<font size="5">Last name*</font><br>
<input type="text" name="last_name" required><br>

<font size="5">First name*</font><br>
<input type="text" name="first_name" required><br>

<font size="5">Middle Initial</font><br>
<input type="text" name="middle_initial" ><br>


<font size="5"><p class="thick">Highest Educational Attainment*</p></font>

<font size="5">

<input class="checked" type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="hsalsgrad" checked /><br>
<input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="hsalsgrad" required> High School Graduate / ALS 
Graduate<br>
<input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="shsgrad" required> Senior High School Graduate<br>
<input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="undergrad1" required> College Undergraduate 1 year<br> 
<input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="undergrad2" required> College Undergraduate 2 years<br> 
<input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="undergrad3" required> College Undergraduate 3 years<br> 
<input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="undergrad4" required> College Undergraduate 4+ 
years<br>
<input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="collegegrad" required> College Graduate<br>
</font><br>
<hr>
<font size="5"><p class="thick">Logic and Reasoning</p></font>

<p>You will be given 5 minutes to complete this portion.</p><br>

<font size="5"><p>The 4:25 P2P bus takes 1 hour and 45 minutes to arrive in 
Trinoma. If Joseph takes this bus, what time will he arrive in 
Trinoma? *</p>


<input class="checked" type="radio" name="logic1" value="0" checked /> </br>
<input type="radio" name="logic1" value="0" required> 7:05 <br>
<input type="radio" name="logic1" value="0" required> 6:25<br>
<input type="radio" name="logic1" value="1" required> 6:10<br>
<input type="radio" name="logic1" value="0" required> 5:55<br>

<br>

<p>Janine’s shoes cost $44.50, her pants cost $20.80 and her t-shirt
cost $14.95. What is the total of her purchases? *</p>

<input class="checked" type="radio" name="logic2" value="0" checked /> </br>
<input type="radio" name="logic2" value="0" required> 85.25<br>
<input type="radio" name="logic2" value="1" required> 80.25<br>
<input type="radio" name="logic2" value="0" required> 82.55<br>
<input type="radio" name="logic2" value="0" required> 80.55<br>

<br>

<p>Which number represents the smallest amount? *</p>

<input class="checked" type="radio" name="logic3" value="0" checked /> </br>
<input type="radio" name="logic3" value="0" required> 1/12<br>
<input type="radio" name="logic3" value="0" required> 2/9<br>
<input type="radio" name="logic3" value="0" required> 15/200<br>
<input type="radio" name="logic3" value="1" required> 3/140<br>
</font>
<br>

<input name="submit" type='submit' id='thebutton' value='Submit' 
onclick="document.getElementById('Label2').innerHTML = 'Clicked!'"></input>

<p hidden id='Label1'> Time </p>
<p hidden id='Label2' style='color:red;'> </p>
```

This should be inserted in ghsadd.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ghsexam_database" ;
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$last_name =$_POST['last_name'];
$first_name =$_POST['first_name'];
$middle_initial =$_POST['middle_initial'];
$educ_attain =$_POST['educ_attain'];

$logic1 =$_POST['logic1'];
$logic2 =$_POST['logic2'];
$logic3 =$_POST['logic3'];

$grammar1 =$_POST['grammar1'];
$grammar2 =$_POST['grammar2'];
$grammar3 =$_POST['grammar3'];
$grammar4 =$_POST['grammar4'];
$grammar5 =$_POST['grammar5'];

$ghs_essay =$_POST['ghs_essay'];

$reading1 =$_POST['reading1'];
$reading2 =$_POST['reading2'];
$reading3 =$_POST['reading3'];
$reading4 =$_POST['reading4'];

$listening1 =$_POST['listening1'];
$listening2 =$_POST['listening2'];

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO ghs_table (last_name, first_name, middle_initial,         
educ_attain, logic1, logic2, logic3, grammar1, grammar2, grammar3, grammar4, grammar5, ghs_essay, 
reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4, listening1, listening2, datentime) values ('$last_name', 
'$first_name', '$middle_initial', '$educ_attain', '$logic1', '$logic2', '$logic3', '$grammar1', 
'$grammar2', '$grammar3', '$grammar4', '$grammar5', '$ghs_essay', '$reading1', '$reading2', 
'$reading3', '$reading4', '$listening1', '$listening2', now() )");

}

else{
    echo" ";
}

mysqli_close($conn); 

?>

<html>
<link rel="icon" href="ghsfavicon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="ghsfavicon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
</head>
<body>

<br>

<center><h1>Exam Successfully Submited!</h1></center>
<center><h3><a href="/ghs/ghsexamhome.php">Submit Another Exam</a></h3></center>


</body>
</html>
```

Just created a database and table base on the ghsadd.php, which is the ghsexam_database, and ghs_table.
The problem here is, when I restarted the WAMP server and try to submit an EXAM, it works normally, like I can submit it and it auto submits also and it was successfully inserted into the database.

but after several minutes, when I will send another response, it auto submit, and I can submit also, but it was not inserted into the database!, and when I will close the chrome, reset all services on the WAMP server, It can work normally, but again after several minutes and submissions, the next submission will fail to insert in the database, without and error messages!,

Is there something like a seesion timeout related? I've been trying to search it out like, if there is session timout of the html form, or the phpmyadmin server itself? It was locally hosted, like I have the main WAMP server and codes in my desktop, but the exams should be done in the 6 laptops the also connected on the same network, You can check this link out,

[Data Submit Interruption of html Form inserting data in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223125/data-submit-interruption-of-html-form-inserting-data-in-mysql)

This Topic will be useful to the aspiring new developers, as well as those teachers who want to create their own exam for the students, as I created this one with 12 minute timer, auto submit or auto-click submit button after timer expires, and setting the blank fields to "0" value when time is up. Its really hard to find one of these in the internet so I just created my own. Thanks in advance for those will help to resolve the topic.

Comment: Dangerous `INSERT`ions. I recommend using mysqli with Prepared Statements. I hope your connection information is really on a separate page in a folder with permission 700 on it.

Comment: `<form action=''`. That's the same page you are on. Learn AJAX while you're at it. Just comments.

Comment: `<input>` is not a container, you shouldn't have `</input>`

Comment: but, the insert statement is on a different php page?

Comment: Well, you are not checking for any php or mysql errors, so you really should not be surprised that you are not getting any error messages...

Comment: Hi, I already knew the problem, it is becuase of this line of code .              
                                                                                                                  <textarea rows="4" cols="100" name="ghs_essay" placeholder="Your Answer" required></textarea><br>                                                                                                          In my phpmyadmin, database and table structure, it was set as;  ghs_essay varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci  No None

Comment: When I leave the text box blank, It 101% submits and insert into the database, but when I filled up the textbox with essay, it fails after several submissions.

Comment: Please Help me, when I'm using special characters like ' or " and any other of it. it wont get inserted in the database, I am using textarea input type tag, but regardless of it, when inserting special characters, it fails.

Comment: The responds here are too slow, I just change the $ghs_essay =$_POST['ghs_essay']; to $ghs_essay = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ghs_essay']); and it works. mysqli_real_escape_string for ignoring special characters and insert it into the database.